# How to send jinja variable to java script

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Target Date</th>
        <th>Estimate</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Actual Hours</th>
        <th>Approved Hours</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Target Date</th>
    </tr>
    {% for val in details %}
        <tr>
            <td><button id={{loop.index}} onclick=myFunction(this)>{{loop.index}}</button>{{val['id']}}</td>
            
            <td>{{val['type']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['name']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['start_date']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['target_date']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['estimate']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['status']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_hours']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['approved_hours']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_start_date']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_target_date']}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<script>
    function myFunction(z){
        var currTR = z.parentNode.parentNode;
        var newTR = document.createElement("tr");
        newTR.innerHTML = "<td>s</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td>";
        currTR.parentNode.insertBefore(newTR, currTR.nextSibling);          
    }
    function some(x){
        
    }
</script>
```

the goal is every time I press the button, it should send some data to my function for the new row it's about to add and the values of that function would be the td that the new row is supposed to add.

```
onclick=myFunction(this,{{val}})

...
<script>
function myFunction(z,l)
...
        newTR.innerHTML = "<td>l[2]</td><td>l[3]</td><td>l[4]</td>";

</script>
```

But I am unable to send the jinja variable to the javascript, and as I am writing this I realize I don't know how to access the data either in javascript. any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing magical about Javascript, it's just a part of your template. Your issue is you are using the quotes incorrectly, i.e. try `var l = '{{ val }}';`

Comment: That worked, but I realized val is a variable made in the for loop, so it gets terminated on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass directly jinja variable to javascript, you have to inject it in your html like this: `<button id={{jinja_var}} onclick=myFunction({{jinja_var}})>`

your code should look something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Target Date</th>
        <th>Estimate</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Actual Hours</th>
        <th>Approved Hours</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Target Date</th>
    </tr>
    {% for val in details %}
        <tr>
            <td><button id={{loop.index}} onclick=myFunction({{loop.index}})>{{loop.index}}</button>{{val['id']}}</td>
            
            <td>{{val['type']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['name']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['start_date']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['target_date']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['estimate']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['status']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_hours']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['approved_hours']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_start_date']}}</td>
            <td>{{val['timesheet_details']['actual_target_date']}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<script>
    function myFunction(z){
        var currTR = z.parentNode.parentNode;
        var newTR = document.createElement("tr");
        newTR.innerHTML = "<td>s</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td>";
        currTR.parentNode.insertBefore(newTR, currTR.nextSibling);          
    }
    function some(x){
        
    }
</script>
```

in the example I used the variable `{{loop.index}}`, but if you have to use a value contained in the object `val` simply replace `{{loop.index}}` with `{{val['my_value']}}`:

```
<button id={{loop.index}} onclick=myFunction({{val['my_value']}})>{{loop.index}}</button>
```